# Python ArangoDB

Tags: python, arangodb

I'm not able anymore to change my database on **arangodb**.

If I try to create a collection I get the error:

> Collection error: cannot create collection: invalid database directory

If I try to delete a collection I get the error:

> Couldn't delete collection.

Besides that some of the collections are now corrupted.
I've been working with this db for 2 months and I'm only getting these errors now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone gets the same error anytime in life, it was just a temporary error due to server overload.